# How to create/call functions inside cellForItemAt in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, label, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a beginner, and I think this is a simple question.

My `cellForItemAt` methods are very lengthy and I would like to create functions to clean them up.

How do you create a function that can work around the `cell.nameLabel.text` that produces the error

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'"?

For example:

```
func setAllCellLabels() { 
   cell.nameLabel1.text = "Name1"
   cell.nameLabel2.text = "Name2" 
} 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NameCell", for: indexPath) as! NameCell 
     setAllCellLabels() 
     return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hey, Xcode is very intelligent, This type of task Xcode do automatically. Just follow the few steps:-**

1:- Select the line of code(for which you make a function)

2:- Press right-click, Under that going to the "Refractor" method

3:- Tap on "Extract to Method". It automatically makes the function and by default, it calls from where it should be extracted.

**Please see in the image:-**

[image]

*This solution is available for-ever in Xcode.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way Sh_Khan says, by adding methods to your customer cell class. Alternatively, you could implement a function like you have now in

```
func setAllLabelsForCell(_ cell: NameCell) {
    cell.nameLabel1.text = "Name1"
    cell.nameLabel2.text = "Name2"
}
```

Note that configuring a cell with the exact same constant data every time is not that useful. You're probably going to want to set up a data model that is an array of the values you want to install into each indexPath in your collection view. You'd then index into your array in your cellForRowAt() method, pull out the data for that cell, and pass it to your cell configuration method.

Say it was an array of structs of type CellData:

```
struct CellData {
   let label1Text: String
   let label2Text: String
}
```

Then your function might look like this:

```
func setAllLabelsForCell(_ cell: NameCell, withData cellData: CellData) {
    cell.nameLabel1.text = cellData.label1Text
    cell.nameLabel2.text = cellData.label2Text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it inside the subclass `NameCell` (Recommended)

```
class NameCell:UICollectionViewCell {
   func setAllCellLabels() { 
      self.nameLabel1.text = "Name1"
      self.nameLabel2.text = "Name2" 
   }
}
```

then call it inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.setAllCellLabels()
```

OR of you need it inside the vc (Not Recommended)

```
func setAllCellLabels(_ cell:NameCell) { 
  self.nameLabel1.text = "Name1"
  self.nameLabel2.text = "Name2" 
}
```

and call it

```
self.setAllCellLabels(cell)
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but by no means the only way.

Comment: @DuncanC i added the other way also

Comment: As I point out in my answer, installing hard-coded values into cells is rarely useful. You almost always want to fetch data from a model object using the indexPath of the cell as an index or key, and then install the fetched model data into the cell.